# How to partially re-join parsed URL?

Tags: python, urlparse

I would like to get scheme and netloc rejoined. Currently I am doing

```
o = urlparse(url)
res = o.scheme + "://" + o.netloc
```

Is this correct and is it possible to use `urljoin` function?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `urlunparse`:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse

parts = urlparse(url)
res = urlunparse(parts[:2] + ('', '', None, None))
```